# preserve MySQL comment in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I have been working on a project where I've been developing the MySQL commands interactively. I now want to run the MySQL commands using a PHP script. I do this by simply pasting in the MySQL commands and making them into a PHP string. Like this...

```
$queryStg = "
    update table1 set col1 = 1;

    drop table table2; 
    ";

$sqlQuery = mysqli_multi_query($mysqliLink, $queryStg);
```

However I've always had to strip out the MySQL comments to get it to work. I'd prefer to retain these comments. Is there a way to do this?. I've tried adding '\n' at the end of each comment but I cant get this to work.
E.g. if I run this it will come back with errors...

```
$queryStg = "
    -- a mySQL comment
    update table1 set col1 = 1;

    --another comment
    drop table table2; 
    ";

$sqlQuery = mysqli_multi_query($mysqliLink, $queryStg);
```

Full code incase its useful

```
$mysqliLink = new mysqli ($host, $username, $password, $dbName);

$queryStg = "
    -- a mySQL comment
    update table1 set col1 = 1;

    --another comment
    drop table table2; 
    ";

$sqlQuery = mysqli_multi_query($mysqliLink, $queryStg);

do {
        if ( mysqli_error($mysqliLink) ) {
        die("ERROR: " .
            htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($mysqliLink), ENT_QUOTES) .
            "<br>\n");
    }

    echo mysqli_affected_rows($mysqliLink);
    mysqli_use_result($mysqliLink);
    $moreResults = mysqli_more_results($mysqliLink);
    @mysqli_next_result($mysqliLink);
} while($moreResults);
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the error that you have multiple queries in one? That shouldn't work with `mysqli_query`  in the first place. Try `mysqli_multi_query()` (I don't know whether that one accepts comments though)

Comment: Thanks @Pekka. It was a typo. Corrected. Still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"select * from
 -- comment
 atable"
```

Gets translated into `"select * from -- comment atable"`
MySQL also allows this type of comments:

> `/*comment that ends*/`

```
"select * from
 /*comment*/
 atable"
```

Gets translated into `"select * from /*comment*/ atable"`

And that does work :-).

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html

Comment: That worked. Thanks very much. I'll use this comment style in future as its just like PHP comments.

Comment: For everyone's info: As you could see in the linked documentation, "-- comment \n" style is allowed. The example query will NOT as stated in Johan's answer be translated into `"select * from -- comment atable"`. mysqli_multi_query() will just ignore the comment.

Comment: @Richard86, yep, but `/*bla*/` always works without issues, and `-- comment /n` can easily be mistyped and the `/n` can be eaten, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Personally, I agree that `/*bla*/` looks better. My comment aimed at give future readers correct info on how comments work with mysqli_multi_query().

Answer (score 7):

Comments will be skipped **EDIT if properly escaped ("-- " needs to be followed by space character, tab, newline etc.)**. Try this instead:

```
$queryStg = "
-- a mySQL comment
update table1 set col1 = 1;

-- another comment
drop table table2; 
";

$sqlQuery = $mysqliLink->multi_query($queryStg);
```

Comment: Raffael: That's not fair, because in the OP's question there was already mention of $mysqliLink, thus it is implied that the OP already knows how to create it.

Comment: Thank you Evert. Just like you said, I found it irrelevant to create a new object with fictitious parameters, since $mysqliLink was used in the OP's question without being created there.

Comment: Thanks @richard86 This was a typo (when I was simplifying things out of my wrapper functions). Code above corrected. Still doesnt work (I presume the change you meant was for the 'multi' bit and not the alternative object based notation.)

Comment: @spiderplant0 Comments will be skipped only if properly escaped. "-- " needs to be followed by space character, tab, newline etc. I didn't first see that the second comment "--another comment" had no space character after "--". Please tell me if the provided code works when changed to "-- another comment".

Comment: +1 to counterract @Raffael, and because it's a nice, simple fix :-)

Comment: @Richard That worked. Thanks very much. Didint realise you need a space (I've been running MySQL interractevly in HeidiSQL and it seems to cope with no spaces after the double dash).

Comment: Now with all the comments your answer gives now enough insights. I give you now the point. But my comment was because the questioner was asking with procedural code and you were answering in OO code. So it could have been that this answer was not fully understood by the questioner.