# Comments are causing errors in MySQL Script

Tags: mysql

I'm using -- and # for comments in my SQL scripts but when I run, it returns error messages about syntax errors. When I take the comments out it runs fine. For examples below cause errors.

```
#################################################
# DELETE RECORDS FROM TABLE
#################################################

-- DELETE RECORDS FROM TABLE WHERE EXTRACT RECORDS CONTAIN DELETE
```

The only comment I can do is # at the beginning of a line which I guess is sufficient but I want to know why this doesn't work. Did this all the time in SQLServer.

Comment: I don't know about any specific reason for `#` comments causing errors (I've had that same issue). But I recommend you change all your comments to `--` to avoid any problems.

Comment: This syntax is fine in mysql.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: Yes, strange - # should work: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html

Comment: Could you post more of the script, that is very odd indeed

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001390/preserve-mysql-comment-in-php-script

Answer (score 6):

Both ways are acceptable for commenting out lines in MySQL scripts.  See [MySQL's documentation on comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html).   The hash at the start of the line is acceptable, as is the double-hyphen **as long as it is followed by a space**, e.g.:

```
-- This line is valid a comment
```

Not putting a space after the double hyphen will cause errors in mysql.

```
--This line is NOT a valid comment
```

If you are putting a space after the double-hyphens, there must be some other reason for the syntax errors.  The example you posted works for me in MySQL without errors.

Comment: The example works for me. The space-issue is something I encounter often (since it comments the line but is still read as an error). Please check this answer as correct @Bob

Answer (score 1):

Comments in SQL start `--` i.e. What you have and that works

But not starting with '#'

So put `--` to start a comment

This is when the database is running in ANSI mode (I guess)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this otherwhise..

```
-- #################################################
-- # DELETE RECORDS FROM TABLE
-- #################################################

-- DELETE RECORDS FROM TABLE WHERE EXTRACT RECORDS CONTAIN DELETE
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html) # is allowed for comments but you may need to add a space between the first and the second one eg: # ######

Comment: The OP is using MySQL